# Cant access Paypal sandbox account profile to get credentials

Tags: paypal, sandbox, profile, account

When a try going to "Sandbox > Accounts > Profile, I got the message "Your request is still processing, please wait..." and thats it. Someone facing the same problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. It's been hours and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) instead.  Login with your sandbox seller account and it will drop you directly into the API credentials screen.